# Prison Riddle: How do they escape?

Tags: lateral-thinking, situation

Two prisoners are locked in a dirt floor cell with nothing but a mattress, a frame, and a stolen spoon. There is a small, bar less window high on the wall, but they can not get to it. First, they try to tunnel out, but decide that it is too much work and will attract attention. Then, they attempt to get out by climbing on the mattress and frame, then climbing on one another, but still are unable to reach the window. They eventually escape.

How do they get out?

Hint: They do not rearrange the mattress.

Comment: You didn't say anything about the walls. How are they locked in?

Comment: Four walled cell. One window. One door.

Comment: **Prisoner != human ?** Typically, such "lateral-thinking" story questions have a high likelyhood to be closed as "too broad". Also "Riddle" does not apply, or does it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even though tunneling out was too much work, maybe they:

> dug enough dirt out from part of their cell to create a mound of dirt sufficiently tall (when combined with the mattress and frame) to allow them to reach the window

Comment: I am ashamed to realize that I've seen this riddle in another form before.

Comment: I thought this at first but I feel it would attract too much attention also.

Answer (score 24):

Although an answer has been marked as correct, here is another solution, which requires only the stolen spoon.

> Since they reportedly are able to dig moderately deep into the wall, they could dig little footholds with the help of which they would be able to reach the window and escape.

Comment: This is probably more practical since they are trying to not attract attention. Having a huge mound of dirt would _surely not_ attract any attention.

Comment: Where does it say that they can do that  (d\_\_ into the w\_\_\_)?

Answer (score 19):

A silly, lateral thinking, wild guess:

> The floor is very hard packed. 
> The door closes very snugly and does not have a window
> (or, if it does, *it* (the window in the door) also closes very snugly). 
> A very severe rainstorm strikes;
> wind blows bucketfuls of rain water in through the window. 
> The water does not soak into the hard-packed dirt floor
> or leak through the tightly sealed door;
> and so the water level increases
> until the prisoners can simply float to the window.

For slightly faster results,

> substitute "tsunami" for "rainstorm".

Comment: I'm speechless...

Comment: That's an amazing answer.

Comment: If the floor is clay-like they could probably even use it to seal the door

Answer (score 10):

Almost certainly:

> The prisoners are children.  Eventually they grow tall enough to reach the window.

Answer (score 9):

One possibility:

> The crime they are in for is stealing a spoon. They "frame" the mattress for the crime and are set free.  (There is a [word-problem](/questions/tagged/word-problem) tag on the question).

An other one:

> Their sentence comes to an end.

Comment: Question states that they _escape_. Don't think that their sentence ending fits the bill so well

Comment: @Ben. Me neither, but I tried to be creative. On the other hand, framing someone/something is still a form of escaping.

Comment: @ben it doesn't say they *illegally* escape

Comment: @question_asker. Good remark, but framing someone is *still* illegal :)

Comment: Good thinking on that one, actually. Although, the "Word Problem" tag was added by a moderator, not me.

Comment: @Larry. I'm a simple man. I see a word problem tag, I try to twist words. nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Marius shhh I'm trying to defend your answer here, don't throw me under the bus

Comment: @question_asker. OK. sorry mister lawyer.  I'll sit down now. Please go on.

Comment: @Marius that's mister lawyer, esquire to you

Comment: Fun fact: the tagging inside spoiler tag markup does not end well.

Comment: @Mindwin maybe we should report this on meta under the new design tread

Answer (score 8):

Guessing this:

> What if they just died in the prison itself? They would escape the realms of earth and the prison along with it

Answer (score 7):

Most of the answers posted so far ignore the clue, which says that they do not rearrange the mattress.

> This is a word puzzle, so "rearrange" suggests an anagram is required.
>
>   Instead of rearranging THE MATTRESS, one of the men rearranges THE FRAME AND THE STOLEN SPOON. The result is THAT DOOR OPENS, THEN MAN FLEES.
>
>   The other man quickly follows him!

Comment: Super! (Markup inside spoilers is somewhat limited. You can fake paragraphs by introducing hard line breaks with extra spaces at the end of a line. You could also use HTML markup. I've modified it.)

Comment: Thanks! It took a lot of playing around to find something that worked. Thanks for fixing my formatting too.

Answer (score 6):

How they reached the window:

And they didn't rearrange the mattress:

> They bounced on the bed to get higher and reach the window

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that

> **They flew out.** The prisoners could have been birds, bats, certain insects, or other creatures that can fly. There's no need to climb if you can go airborne.

Admittedly, this doesn't seem to match the hint.

Comment: I have to say, interesting thinking on that one, although it is not the right answer, I appreciate the creativity.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility (just about) compatible with everything in the question is that

> the door is locked from the inside. The prisoners are extremely stupid, which is why they tried complicated things like climbing out of the window before it occurred to them to unlock the door.

> (It's a combination lock, which is why "the key to the door" was not listed among the prisoners' assets.)

Answer (score 2):

Using the concave surface of the spoon to focus the suns rays coming through the window, they are able to melt the lock on the door.  Unfortunately, this is noticed by the guard when they are next served a meal, (they were waiting for dark before they left) and the spoon is confiscated.  However, they were in for the offence of pickpocketing, and were able to steal a set of skeleton keys from the locksmith as he repaired the door.  By jamming these into the wall, they were able to make footholds, and climbed up and out of the window later that night.

Comment: But what about the panda, the shaggy dog & the unicorn?  Where do they fit in?    :-)    ⁠

Comment: The shaggy dog had already eaten the Unicorn - aside from it's horn, which the doughty duo used to fend off the (ravenous) panda.  The short sighted guard the next morning saw the panda, and thinking that it was the shorter of the two jailbirds, bought it up before the beak.  Meanwhile the two escaped to a life of petty crime as the police were searching for a single fugitive.  The prison governor's office is to this day decorated with a Unicorn-hide carpet; the panda got ten-to-life.    I assumed that was all obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> Is the door even locked?  They opened it and left maybe?

or

> Or cold the mattress be very springy?  They jumped out? (Cripes!  Someone beat me to it.)

or

> One of them plays dead, the other hits the investigating guard with the spoon and then dresses up as the guard and makes it look like he's transferring the other prisoner.  Poof!  They're gone!

I know it's been answered correctly now but I'd been sitting racking my brain and I'd come up with another possibility.  The prisoners are children.  They grow taller over time and can then reach the window to escape.  Admittedly not a likely answer but it made me giggle.

Comment: 1. Question states they're _locked in_ . 2. You shot yourself in the foot.. 3. Knock him out _with a spoon_? If spoon is capable of knocking people out i doubt they would have been allowed to keep it.

Comment: Oh yeah...  :|  I really want to know this one.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Possible</s> WRONG answer

> They use the spoon to dig in the floor and go out?

Other answer

> They use the spoon as a lockpick.

Comment: The question mentions that they didn't tunnel out.

Answer (score 0):

> They break the spoon in half... Two halves make a whole, and they crawl out the (w)hole! :)